# Prometheus and Grafana Hourly Rollup Query

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I'm trying to build a graph in Grafana that aggregates a metric over hour time periods. So like there'll be aggregation for 11-12, 12-1, etc and from the start of the hour till now.

I've figured out how to aggregate metrics over the last hour of time passed (e.g., if it's 12:11 now, then it'll aggregate from 11:11 to 12:11), but not the way I just described. Does anyone have any ideas? Is it possible to even do what I'm describing?

I haven't done much work with either of these packages before, so my own knowledge is minimalist at best and I haven't found much in online resources either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to aggregate a metric over hour long-time periods? Is it a gauge or a counter you are using?

Comment: We are building a monitoring tool that will help us to verify that our system is working correctly. We aggregate over the hour time period because the system we are monitoring should have similar output.

I'm using gauges for both.